# Capturar fecha al hacer click en botón de ingreso

Tags: php, html, date

Tengo un login básico, con usuarios y contraseñas. Cada vez que ingresan necesito saber la fecha en la que lo hace, necesito capturar la fecha en la que hace click al botón ingresar, entiendo que debe ser algo como "getDate()" que se almacene en una variable para luego capturarla o something like that :( Ayudaaa

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida en la comunidad te recomiendo que agregues el código que has utilizado y que error te ha arrojado, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tengas una idea más clara de como preguntar correctamente, saludos !

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la `Date` Seria algo como:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {

  $fecha = date('c'); //fecha
}
```